# Attempting to set up Wireless Access Point or WiFi Extender without an Ethernet connection

Tags: wifi

To start, I have been trying to get this project to work for about 3 months with quite a bit of research. I have used multiple guides such as [this from the RasPi documentation site.](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/computers/configuration.html#setting-up-a-routed-wireless-access-point) However, I cannot figure out how to set up either a routed access point or WiFi extender without being connected to Ethernet. Is this even possible? Could someone lead me in the correct direction?

Comment: What is the point of "either a routed or bridged access point' without? What are you ACTUALLY trying to do?

Comment: There isn't a point of routed vs bridged, I was just confused. I want routed. I went ahead and edited my post. I am just trying to extend the WiFi in my home without purchasing another router. I do not want to have to snake an ethernet cable to my Pi in my room so I am attempting to make an extender or access point without Ethernet.

Comment: What are you trying to route between if you say "without Ethernet"? Routing is when you send traffic from one network (IP network) to another network (IP network). They can be on different interfaces (most common) or not. And if you reefer to "multiple guides" then add them to your question, not just vaguely saying "multiple guides"!